# How to prevent djagno from updating certain fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that I use in django admin to keep track of action taken on a task. The model includes a user field to show which user added an action. The issue is when a new task update is added, django overwrite the previous user by the new user. As it can be seen bellow, I do not want to change the user (by field) whenever a new action is created.

```
class Action(models.Model):
   action = models.ForeignKey(TaskAction, models.CASCADE)
   by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', models.CASCADE)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
   note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.action)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Task Action'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Task Actions'
    db_table = 'task_actions'
```

Answer (score 1):

In admin.py  set  readonly field for 'by' read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

```
class ActionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     readonly_fields=('by',)
```

Comment: Thank you but the 'by' field of previously created action object still gets updated automatically when a new action is added. For instance, after user A created an action, if user B created another action the 'by' field for object A is overwritten as user B